# IF ELSE statement is producing invalid syntax in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure why this is returning invalid syntax:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddColor`(
                            IN hexvalue varchar(7),
                          IN notes varchar(50))
    BEGIN
    IF hexvalue REGEXP '^#[0-9A-F]{6}$' THEN

       INSERT INTO data.colors(hexvalue,notes) VALUES (hexvalue,notes);

    ELSE

       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '400'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid hex value specified';

    END IF;
    END
```

There doesn't seem to be any errors when writing it in.

Comment: Are you sure you have issued `DELIMITER //` or similar as described here? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html You code works otherwise except `SQLSTATE '400'` should be changed to a 5 digit number.

Comment: @SalmanA SQLSTATE not being 5 characters was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following [official documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

> The condition_value in a SIGNAL statement indicates the error value to be returned. It can be an SQLSTATE value **(a 5-character string literal)** or a condition_name that refers to a named condition previously defined with DECLARE ... CONDITION (see Section 13.6.7.1, “DECLARE ... CONDITION Syntax”).

Try the following syntax and change SIGNAL SQLSTATE value to `04000`:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddColor`(
                    IN hexvalue varchar(7),
                    IN notes varchar(50))
BEGIN
IF  (hexvalue REGEXP '^#[0-9A-F]{6}$') THEN

        INSERT INTO data.colors(`hexvalue`,`notes`) VALUES (hexvalue,notes);

    ELSE

        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '04000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid hex value specified';

    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That did not work. Still says syntax error. I should add that the IF statement worked just fine as is. The error occurs after adding the ELSE statement. So the problem must be there somewhere

Comment: @kravb try putting `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '400' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid hex value specified';` on the same row

Comment: I am getting error with SQLSTATE  400 `Bad SQLSTATE: '400'`

Comment: Try another sql state value then

Comment: @kravb it is not throwing a syntax error, you didn't mentioed the right exception

Comment: Yes, just saw someone else post that answer as well. 5 characters are required.

Comment: @kravb i updated my answer and added more details check it out.